# How to get coordinates of a place with google GoogleAutocomplete.getPlacePredictions

Tags: google-maps, ionic5

I am trying to use Google autocomplete API.
The following is the code I have added which returns the address and place id

```
this.GoogleAutocomplete.getPlacePredictions({ input: this.autocomplete.input },
(predictions, status) => {
  this.autocompleteItems = [];
  this.zone.run(() => {
    predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
      this.autocompleteItems.push(prediction);
    });
  });
});
```

I am getting the following response from the API call-

```
description: "Hong Kong"
matched_substrings: [{…}]
place_id: "ChIJD5gyo-3iAzQRfMnq27qzivA"
reference: "ChIJD5gyo-3iAzQRfMnq27qzivA"
structured_formatting: {main_text: 'Hong Kong', main_text_matched_substrings: Array(1)}
terms: [{…}]
types: (3) ['country', 'political', 'geocode']
```

I am new to this and can only find ways to get addresses from coordinates. Is there a way to
get latitude and longitude coordinates with the address/place_id in Ionic 5.

Comment: It's all in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service) really: *`place_id` is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. To retrieve information about the place, pass this identifier in the placeId field of a Place Details request.* Also you should use session tokens. Again, everything is explained on that page.

Comment: Duplicate of [How can i get address components using Google's AutocompleteService via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141220/how-can-i-get-address-components-using-googles-autocompleteservice-via-javascri)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me-

```
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode(
  { address: loc },
  (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      return {
        lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
        lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
      }
    }
  });
return;
```

}